# What does this mean? "He started evening classes."

Tags: sentence-patterns

> "Andrew has just started evening classes. He's studying German."

I just came across this sentence in *Grammar in Use*. This was a example sentence, there's no more context.

From the latter part of the sentence, I assumed that he started taking evening classes. But I'm just a little confused why it is not "Andrew has just started taking evening classes." I think it would be more accurate.

I mean, "ABC college started evening classes." sounds right to me, but the above sentence ... I don't know. I just Googled it and found some books using "somebody started classes" in the book.

Can it mean somebody started taking classes as well?

Comment: Well, _your_ sentence could just as well be "started _offering_..."  But the sample sentence from the book sounds OK.

Comment: @Cascabel: Indeed. *Andrew has just started evening classes. He's **teaching** German.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmmn...you are right. When put that way it could be ambiguous.

Comment: May I suggest changing the title from "What does this mean" to "Isn't this ambiguous".

Comment: I don't see the point of this question. Obviously ***start [noun]*** can have a range of different meanings, depending on both the specific noun ***and*** the context. We'd all agree on what ***start the car*** means in the most common contexts. But it's not hard to imagine an auctioneer selling off the entire contents of some stately home that happens to have a highly-desirable classic car in the garage. In which case there might be a bunch of vintage car dealers hanging around - not bidding for anything else, because they're just waiting for the auctioneer to start the car [auction].

Comment: It appears that Andrew has applied to, and been accepted by, some school or college in his area that offers evening classes in German, and that those classes started a very short time ago--a few days ago, most likely--so it is quite proper and unambiguous to say, "Andrew has just started evening classes...."  Making the sentence "...started taking evening classes..." is OK, but not necessary, unless you have some reason to emphasize that Andrew had, perhaps, been taking daytime classes, but had decided to take evening classes instead.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Surely even "Andrew has just started *taking* evening classes" is ambiguous? Academic Andrew's wife to friend: *Andrew has just started **taking** evening classes. He's teaching German*, He's managed to avoided taking the Literacy 'late-shift' for ages, but, this year the dean forced him!

Comment: I note that the OP does not say that Andrew was *teaching* German in an evening class, but rather he recently started taking evening classes in German, i.e., learning German in an evening class, which is how I would understand the OP.  Now it *could be* that he was an instructor in German and had been assigned to teach an evening class in that language, and he agreed to do so, so that it could be said "he took an evening class [in German] as one of his teaching duties".  But this is unlikely, since the second sentence says he was *studying*, not *teaching*, German.

Comment: "Andrew has just started *taking* evening classes" implies that Andrew's first evening class was recent, whereas "Andrew has just started evening classes" could be an explanation as to why Andrew isn't home with no indication of how recent the first of his evening classes was.

Answer (score 2):

If it was only "Andrew has just started evening classes", then *perhaps* the potential ambiguity is worth resolving, but without further context, English speakers will resolve the ambiguity towards Andrew=student.

But, you presented *two* consecutive sentences, "Andrew has just started evening classes. He's studying German." Together they are unambiguous, and your introduction of "taking" is unnecessary. We know precisely what is meant. Unnecessary disambiguation often feels unnatural.

Comment: Yeah, but if you think like FumbleFingers for a moment, you can come up with meanings like "Andrew teaches something in the evening, because he takes German classes during the day".

Answer (score 0):

The sentence *"Andrew has started classes"* means that Andrew has begun to do something with the classes but it leaves unstated what exactly he is doing with the classes.  Without further context, we *might* assume that he is a student only because there tend to be many student in a class and only one teacher.  If the context was that he was a teacher we might assume that he is teaching the class.  If he is a school cleaner, we might assume that he is cleaning the classroom.

The sentence is ambiguous.  By including "taking" (or "giving"), you can make the sentence less ambiguous but also less concise.

Comment: Then, if he is a school cleaner, he could simply say "I've started the classroom." meaning he started cleaning the classroom? And that is better than saying "I've started cleaning the classroom." Am I correct?

Comment: @user227026: Yes. Provided that it was clear from the context that the action was cleaning, it is idiomatic to say that.